# window.open terminated the universal application

Tags: uwp, winjs, window.open

I am creating an application Universial Windows 10 using WinJS. But my application is always crashed once I call the function window.open. Here is the code:

ref = window.open(authorizationUri, '_blank', 'location=yes')

```
        if (!ref) {
            deferred.reject(new Microsoft.Utility.Exception('The logon dialog was blocked by popup blocker'));
        } else {
            ref.addEventListener('loadstart', onRedirect);
            if (window["tinyHippos"]) {
                window["__rippleFireEvent"] = onRedirect;
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help me plz? Many many thanks!!!

Comment: What is your authorizationUri?

Comment: In fact, I try to authentificate users with Office365 API. Once the user is not authentificated, a web browser is openned to prompt the user to log in with her credentials (username, password). The authorizationUri is like:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&resource=Microsoft.SharePoint&client_id={clienId}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}
It works for WP8, Android, but not with universial windows app.

Answer (score 0):

window.open is not supported in UWP. The link below showed that
[HTML and DOM API changes list (HTML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700404.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this bug using WebAuthenticationBroker class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx